# ifstream doesn't read wanted values

Tags: c++, pcap

In an attempt to read a pcap's global file header, using the main code:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("test.pcap", std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);

    pcap_header gheader(in);


    in.close();

    return 0;
}
```

and the following gheader constructor:

```
pcap_header::pcap_header(std::ifstream& in)
{
    in >> magic_number;
    in >> version_major;
    in >> version_minor;
    in >> thiszone;
    in >> sigfigs;
    in >> snaplen;
    in >> network;

    // debug
    std::cout << std::hex << magic_number << " " << version_major << " " << version_minor << " " << thiszone << " " << sigfigs << " " << snaplen<< " "  << network << std::endl;
}
```

the returned output is:

```
0 ffcc 28 75b97220 38369fae fffffffe 75b8413a
```

instead of:

```
a1b2c3d4 2 4 0 0 40000 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're opening the file as binary: `std::ifstream::binary` but then reading like it's a text file. If it's a text file then remove `std::ifstream::binary`.

Comment: Yes, you need to use `read()` instead of `operator>>` when reading binary data.  `operator>>` only works on formatted text.